# How to create UIGestureRecognizer in subview with Autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uigesturerecognizer

When I attempt to use a UIGestureRecognizer in a subview whose frame is dictated through Autolayout in the superviewcontroller, it does not respond to the gesture. I believe this to be because the gesture recognizer is unaware of the true dimensions of the view, as described by the Autolayout constraints. How can this be fixed? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var delegate: MyProtocolForSwipeRecognition!
    var gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    init() {
        gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: delegate, action: "swiped")
        super.init(frame: CGRect()) //<- I believe my problem is because it thinks
        //the frame is this empty CGRect, but I don't know what else to put here.
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach (Auto Layout is not the problem):

1. You have to set `userInteractionEnabled = true` on your `MyLabel` class
2. You have to make sure that `delegate` is not nil when you add the gesture recognizer. You can do that by adding an initializer that takes the delegate as parameter

Here is how to make it work (no need to keep a reference to the gesture recognizer):

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    var delegate: MyProtocolForSwipeRecognition

    init(withDelegate delegate: MyProtocolForSwipeRecognition) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: delegate, action: "swiped")
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize your label in the class that implements your protocol:

```
let label = MyLabel(withDelegate: self)
```